# MGF of a random sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I am doing this quesiton right now and I don't even know how to start it up.
I know that it's in relation to a sum of a random number of random variables, but I don't know how to continue on from that.

I've read my textbook and it states some definition for an MGF which is:
$M_{y}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_{X}(t)^n p_{N}(n)$ but it doesn't derive it, however, I think it relates to this question?

The question is as follows: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: condition on the service time.